# Why I am not able to run rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I did.

```
> git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git
> cd rails
> cd railties
> rake
```

And I got following error.

```
(in /Users/dorelal/dev/scratch/rails/railties)
./test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb:236:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /Users/dorelal/dev/scratch/rails/railties/tmp/app_template/config/boot.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    from ./test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb:236:in `open'
    from ./test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb:236
    from ./test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb:222:in `initialize'
    from ./test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb:222:in `new'
    from ./test/isolation/abstract_unit.rb:222
    from test/application/configuration_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from test/application/configuration_test.rb:1
rake aborted!
```

I checked ~/railties/tmp and this directory is empty.

I know rails is not broken. So what am I missing?

Comment: Which branch are you in?

Comment: By default I am in master branch which is rails edge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `bundle install` after you `cd rails`. That will install all the gems required by your new Rails repo, including minitest (test-unit at the time of your question.)

After you run `bundle install`, you will be able to run the rails tests by doing a `cd` into the component directory and then either running the entire test suite for that component, or specifying a single test file, as follows (using actionpack as an example):

To run all tests for actionpack:

```
cd actionpack
TEST_DIR=generators bundle exec rake test
```

To run the tests for actionpack test/dispatch/rack_test.rb:

```
cd actionpack
bundle exec ruby -Itest test/dispatch/rack_test.rb
```

To run the entire test suite for all of rails:

```
cd rails
bundle exec rake test
```

A Necromancer cannot resist such a question - so old, yet so relevant, so cleanly asked, so not documented properly.